# Python GUI doesn't respond after the server creation

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, localhost

I tried to make a Tkinter GUI where you specify the port and it creates a local server with the given port, but when I try to execute the script, the local server works, but the GUI doesn't want to respond anymore.

[image]

Here is the source code of the script:

https://github.com/Medshi8/Random_Gui/blob/main/testServer.py

Comment: You need to run the server in a thread.

Comment: could you show me how I have no idea how threading works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to do the function on a separate thread, like:

```
import threading
....
localcnct = Button(CreatserverFrame, text="Creat Server", fg="green"  , command=threading.Thread(target=LocalServ).start)
localcnct.grid(row = 1, column = 2, rowspan= 2 , ipady = 10, ipadx = 5)
```

This should allow you start the function on a separate thread other than tkinters thread, which wont freeze the GUI, when you run this `LocalServ()`. Though keep in mind, pressing button more than once will give an error.

But since the GUI never responds, I dont think the server is being created(in the process of creation). The time that the GUI takes to respond, is the time it takes for the creation of server.

Comment: There are issues in your code: `localcnct` will be None; `start` should be `start()` inside the lambda.  Also normally socket server cannot be run more than one instance as the address cannot be bound twice.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback I appreciate it this will help alot

Answer (score 0):

Below is a simple example running the server in a thread:

```py
import tkinter as tk
import threading
from http.server import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler

class Serv(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(b'Hello')

server = None

def LocalServ():
    global server
    def server_task():
        print('Starting server ...')
        httpd = HTTPServer(('localhost', 8000), Serv)
        httpd.serve_forever()

    # make sure only one server task is running
    if server is None:
        server = threading.Thread(target=server_task, daemon=True)
        server.start()

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('400x300')

tk.Button(root, text='Start Server', command=LocalServ).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, i appreciate your help this worked for me